# What would cause me not to be able to send my newly created token?

Tags: solidity

I've created a new token on the Ropsten test network and I can see the token under my account in MetaMask. When I click on send in MetaMask, from the account that created it with, I can only send ether but not my token?

What could cause this?

Comment: Welcome (I see you're new). You will probably get a much better response to your question if you provide more detail such as the snippit of source code you're trying to interact with, and importantly a link to the contract on etherscan (assuming you've uploaded the source). But first, spend a few minutes searching around in previous answers using tags for tokens or solidity to try to find your answer. I'm not certain of this, but this question feels like it has probably already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 2):

Metamask doesn't support sending of tokens. You can use MyEtherWallet's [connect with Metamask](https://support.metamask.io/kb/article/19-sending-tokens-with-metamask-and-myetherwallet) feature to send tokens from your Metamask wallet.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can see my token in myetherwallet, when I try and send it to a 2nd account, nothing happens when I click generate transaction and when I check ethplorer, nothing appears. I have 5 'fake' ether from the faucet but I don't see it under my account balance in MEW. Would that be why my generate transaction isn't working?

Comment: When I try and send the faucet eth I get an error red screens when everything processes and connects to metamask and then I click submit?

When I try to send my custom token through metamask/MEW it does not generate raw data or do anything when I click on "Generate Transaction"

I'm dead in the water if no one has any ideas.

Comment: As it turns out MEW is saying an error message of:

" (error_21) Not a valid ERC-20 token "

Here is the code:

https://gitlab.com/pedram31/cryptocoopx-ccx/blob/master/ccx-src.sol

Answer (score 0):

Inside of my ether wallet, I had to choose the Ropsten testnet (infura.io) in the upper right corner.

After this I could add the custom token in the bottom right using the contract address, abbreviation and decimals or load the token if given the option. It will then show in the bottom right under Token Balances. After that I could send it through MEW